# Generate an "expired" SSL certificate with keytool

Tags: keystore, keytool

I am creating my keystore with following command:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore myStore.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 1024 -alias myAlias
```

How could I generate one with a past expiry date (the use of this? I want to test the behavior of my app with an expired certificate).

Comment: Just change date on your computer and then create certificate with validity of 1 day. I use TinyCA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the java keytool, the minimum validity for a keystore certificate can be 1 day.

EDIT: looks like there's an option for `-startdate` as @shyam0191 has answered.

So, you **can't(correction: you can actually)** generate a certificate with a past date. I suggest using the following command, which will generate a certificate with a 1-day validity and the next day you will be able to test with it:

```
keytool -selfcert -alias Test -genkey -keystore myStore.keystore -keyalg RSA -validity 1
```

or use @shyam0191's answer which will have the same end result in the end (but sooner).

Comment: The idea from @grep works exactly as needed. Just change the date of your computer to a past date and then create the certificate. It works on Windows 7, I just did it.

Comment: use the -startdate and you can generate certs that are expired. -startdate -2d -validity 1

Comment: You're right @fhanik. Probably I wasn't aware of that option at the time I answered. Either way, it can have the same end result.

Answer (score 13):

You can generate expired certificate using keytool command by using the following parameters.

-startdate

-validity

while validity parameter takes only number of days as input, startdate parameter can be used to mention since when validity begins. The format for input to startdate parameter [yyyy/mm/dd][HH:MM:SS]

Refer to this link for details
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Comment: -startdate -2d -validity 1 (is the simplest form)

Answer (score 8):

You can use below `openssl` commands to generate expired certificates, which mimics the official process to sign certificates.

**Note**: Only tested on Linux.

## Assume yourself as a CA

```
#Create CA key, which means you are now the CA using root.key and root.cer to sign certificates
openssl genrsa 4096 > root.key
#Create CA certificate expired ten years later
openssl req -new -x509 -key root.key -out root.cer -days 3650
```

## Now, you are the one applying a signed certificate from CA

```
#Generates your own private key 
openssl genrsa 4096 > server.key
#Build a Certificate Signing Request
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

## Now you are the CA again

```
#sign the certificate and make the certificate expired 1 day ago. Pay attention to the negative -days argument( not working on MacOS )
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA root.cer -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out server.cer -days -1
```

## Then you can check the dates

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in server.cer
```

`Validity
            Not Before: Mar  7 09:11:13 2019 GMT
            Not After : Mar  6 09:11:13 2019 GMT`